# Back Navigation in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Navigation Drawer (MainMenu.class config)
First MainMenu load NewRadioFragment then i click button at NewRadioFragment start to ViewPager, ViewPager have (PlayRadioFragment and BlogContentFragment) View through ViewPagerActivity ( FragmentActivity ).

Now, I want Back Button in Actionbar back from PlayRadioFragment to NewRadioFragment.

I need help !.

Update

```
private void setImageView(ImageView src, View rootView) {
        image_disk = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.base);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Bitmap bimit = Utils.loadBitmap(image_url);
                image_disk.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        image_disk.setImageBitmap(bimit);
                        prg_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tv_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

When i click function don't finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:

    Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
    if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
        // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
        // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                // Navigate up to the closest parent
                .startActivities();
    } else {
        // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
        // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
    }
    return true;
 }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

or
try this instead

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

or 
call

```
Finish();
```

Comment: First ! thanks for reply. I add code in onOptionsItemSelect ?

Comment: I tried use your code. But give me NullPointerExeption, at line 
Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
I show Log.i("", "TAG "+upIntent); give value null

Comment: try the new snipped i've added

Comment: try to use finish(); and tell me what happen then

Comment: Yesterevening ! I use it. It work but when i click again... PlayRadio don't finish load UI Thread. I update code above

Comment: Oke.. Thanks @Gatunox. I fix it, and now code work :)

Comment: In add some code onResume() and work fine. 
in OptionItemSelect i call finish().

Comment: You should use the parent activity propriety in the manifest instead